# Getting sizeof variable number of arguments

Tags: c

I want bug variable to be dynamic and depending upon sizeof(cmd+args) passed to it

```
void excmd(const char* cmd, ...) {
    char buf[100]; // I want it to be dynamic like size of(cmd+args)
    va_list args;
    va_start(args,cmd); 
    vsnprintf(buf,sizeof(buf),cmd,args);
    system(buf);
    va_end(args);
}
```

Comment: This looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  What actual **problem** are you trying to solve?

Comment: I recommend e.g. [this `vprintf` (and family) reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/vfprintf). Pay close attention to what the `vsnprintf` function *returns*, especially if the buffer is a null pointer and the size is zero.

Comment: I need buf variable to be Dynamic it's hard to guess how long user gives the input string like a path to a file or something

Comment: @XeXkek Some programmer dude's comment is almost the answer you're looking for.

Comment: When I use char *but, and use vsprintf to not include passing sizeof buffer than program crashes and sends signal SIGSEGV

Comment: Please read my comment and the linked reference again. I'm sure it will click after a couple of times.

Comment: I have done reading it and it says if it's a null pointer than it'll crash

Comment: No, that's not what the reference I linked to says. It says that if the buffer is a null pointer, and the size is zero, then the function will return the space needed (excluding the terminator).

Comment: Oh I got it first I'll use num=vprintf to get size needed and than I'll pass that size to vsnprintf as sizeof(num+1)

Comment: Don't forget to actually allocate the buffer!

Answer (score 3):

You probably want something like this:

```
void excmd(const char* cmd, ...) {
  char *buf = NULL;
  va_list args;

  va_start(args, cmd);
  int sizeneeded = vsnprintf(buf, 0, cmd, args) + 1;
  va_end(args);

  buf = malloc(sizeneeded);

  va_start(args, cmd);
  vsnprintf(buf, sizeneeded, cmd, args);
  va_end(args);

  system(buf);    
  free(buf);
}
```

or

```
void excmd(const char* cmd, ...) {
  va_list args;

  va_start(args, cmd);
  int sizeneeded = vsnprintf(NULL, 0, cmd, args) + 1;
  va_end(args);

  char buf[sizeneeded];

  va_start(args, cmd);
  vsnprintf(buf, sizeneeded, cmd, args);
  va_end(args);

  system(buf);    
}
```

Comment: Nice one but one correction that's this should be int sizeneeded = vsnprintf(NULL, 0, cmd, args)+1; to also reserve space for terminator

Comment: @XeXkek you're right, answer edited. You can remove the comments. Thanks.

Comment: As an optimization,  you can make the first call to `vsnprintf()` with a fixed-size buffer, something like 512, 1024, or maybe even 4096 bytes.  That way, if it does fit, you don't have to allocate memory and make the `vsnprintf()` call a second time. You might as well use the results of the first call if you can do so without doing it again.